# Best way to Import mysql DB to Bigquery

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds, google-bigquery

At the moment we have a script that creates a dump of DB and rolls it on Amazon RDS server. This happens hourly and when new dump arrives the previous version of it is removed.

I'm looking to have this data in Bigquery. What would be the easiest process to do this? Particularly:

1. Is there a way to upload a dump to BQ automatically removing the previous version?
2. Is there any way automatically copy DB from RDS to BQ removing the previous version on BQ side?

Any other insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40639993/5221944? what you tried so far?

Comment: i didn't try so far as im considering the best approach at the moment

Comment: to get the best you need first to try good ones! :o)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Mikhail. I'm looking for some useful help with my question here.

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better of to change the dump process than try to create an importing script this way. Streaming new records into BigQuery would be the easiest way to do this. If you are stuck with the dump process you described, then Apache Airflow would a good option as Mikhail suggested.