# How to automate streaming inserts and updates happening in relational table into Google bigquery table?

Tags: mysql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table in my relational database which continually updates and new rows are added.

I want to stream these changes to a replica table which I am maintaining in  Bigquery dataset.

I under stand i can use the following code to do streaming insert

```
def stream_data(dataset_id, table_id, json_data):
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
data = json.loads(json_data)

# Get the table from the API so that the schema is available.
table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)

rows = [data]
errors = bigquery_client.create_rows(table, rows)

if not errors:
    print('Loaded 1 row into {}:{}'.format(dataset_id, table_id))
else:
    print('Errors:')
    pprint(errors)
```

The problem with above code is that, it assumes I have the rows that got added/updated in my relational table.
Is there something I can do to stream the changes/additions as it happens in the relational table to its replica table in bigquery?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629086/how-to-sync-mysql-into-bigquery-in-realtime

Comment: @GrahamPolley 
Yes, my question is exactly that.

Comment: Ok, cool. I'll flag it as a duplicate in that case.