# ETL to bigquery using airflow without have permission cloud storage/ cloud sql

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, etl, airflow

i have done ETL from MySql to bigQuery with python, but because i haven't permission to connect google cloud storage/ cloud sql, i must dump data and partition that by last date, this way easy but didn't worth it because take a much time, it is possible to ETL using airflow from MySql/mongo to bigQuery without google cloud storage/ cloud sql ?

Comment: Can you describe more your architecture? Where is host your MySQL? why do you have storage/cloud sql role issue? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have simple architecture, sources from MySQL workbench (with username, pass, n address) and mongodb. My goal is built data warehouse in bigquery table, but I've read reference that needed cloud storage (or maybe other Google cloud feature that I've forgot) to dump data. Any idea?

Comment: Cloud Storage is the staging ground in GCP. means that if you want to transfer between service, most likely you will have to put them to Cloud Storage first then import them to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

With airflow or not, the easiest and the most efficient way is to:

- Extract data from data source
- Load the data into a file
- Drop the file into Cloud Storage
- Run a BigQuery Load Job on these files (load job is free)

If you want to avoid to create a file and to drop it into Cloud Storage, another way is possible, much more complex: stream data into BigQuery.

- Run a query (MySQL or Mongo)
- Fetch the result.
- On each line, stream write the result into BigQuery ([Streaming is not free on BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#streaming_pricing))

Described like this, it does not seam very complex but:

- You have to maintain the connexion to the source and to the destination during all the process
- You have to handle errors (read and write) and be able to restart at the last point of failure
- You have to perform bulk stream write into BigQuery for optimizing performance. Size of chunks has to be choose wisely.
- Airflow bonus: You have to define and to write your own custom operator for doing this.

By the way, I strongly recommend to follow the first solution.

**Additional tips**: now, [BigQuery can directly request into Cloud SQL database](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). If you still need your MySQL database (for keeping some referential in it) you can migrate it into CloudSQL and perform a join between your Bigquery data warehouse and your CloudSQL referential.

Comment: drop file into cloud storage isn't free n i haven't permission to access cloud sql too, i have a plan to doing ETL with these way:                                                                                   1. load data into big query with dump data and real data that partition by unique key (that has been order by) that called staging process, it is worth it doing this using airflow? @guillaume

Comment: not sure that airflow is the best for this. A simple process can do it easily. However, airflow is convenient for retry on errors and scheduling. All depends of your needs. So, just a word about Cloud Storage. It's free to drop file, but not free to let file in it. If you drop your file, load the data into bigquery and delete them just after, the cost will be in cts (chose a standard regional class). Compare this cost at your cost/hour for engineering another solution!

Comment: any other ways doing ETL to big query without create dump data ?

Comment: Of course you can. There is a lot of cool stuff in bigquery for this. Like UDF that you can write in JS, stored procedure and script. Finally, it boils down to make a query. However, how do you drop your data from MySQL/Mongo to BigQuery?

Comment: i didn't drop dump data, i ignore and always make 2 table (dump and real table), disposition dump is append and disposition real table is truncate, it's work

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to synchronize MySQL databases to BigQuery with Airflow.
You would of course need to make sure you have properly authenticated connections to Airflow DAG workflow.

Also, make sure to define which columns from MySQL you would like to pull and load into BigQuery. You want to also choose the method of loading your data. Would you want it loaded incrementally or fully? Be sure to also formulate a technique for eliminating duplicate copies of data (de-duplicate).

You can find more information on this topic through through this link:
[How to Sync Mysql into Bigquery in realtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629086/how-to-sync-mysql-into-bigquery-in-realtime)

Here is a great resource for setting up your bigquery account and authentications:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAwWSxJpFQ8

You can also have a look at stichdata.com  (https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/mysql/google-bigquery/)

The Stitch MySQL integration will ETL your MySQL to Google BigQuery in minutes and keep it up to date without having to constantly write and maintain ETL scripts. Google Cloud Storage or Cloud SQL won’t be necessary in this case.

For more information on aggregating data for BigQuery using Apache Airflow you may refer to the link below:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-aggregate-data-for-bigquery-using-apache-airflow